# Sort exceeds limit on text search?

Tags: mongodb

I have defined an index like this:

```
db.imageProperties.createIndex(
  {
    "imageProperties.cameraMaker": "text",
    "imageProperties.cameraModel": "text",
    "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1,
  },
  { name: "TextIndex" }
)
```

But, when I try to run a query with a sort like this:

```
 db.imageProperties.find( { $text: { $search: "nikon" } }, {"imagePath" : 1, _id: 0 } ).sort( { "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1 } )
```

I get this error:

```
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
        "code" : 96,
        "codeName" : "OperationFailed"
```

It is my understanding from reading the documentation that it would be possible to combine text search with sorting by creating a combined index as I have done.

This is the output from .explain() on the above query:

```
> db.imageProperties.find( { $text: { $search: "nikon" } }, {"imagePath" : 1, _id: 0 } ).sort( { "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1 } ).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner": {
        "plannerVersion": 1,
        "namespace": "olavt-images.imageProperties",
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$text": {
                "$search": "nikon",
                "$language": "english",
                "$caseSensitive": false,
                "$diacriticSensitive": false
            }
        },
        "queryHash": "1DCFCE0B",
        "planCacheKey": "650B3A8E",
        "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
            "transformBy": {
                "imagePath": 1,
                "_id": 0
            },
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "SORT",
                "sortPattern": {
                    "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1
                },
                "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "TEXT",
                        "indexPrefix": {

                        },
                        "indexName": "TextIndex",
                        "parsedTextQuery": {
                            "terms": [
                                "nikon"
                            ],
                            "negatedTerms": [],
                            "phrases": [],
                            "negatedPhrases": []
                        },
                        "textIndexVersion": 3,
                        "inputStage": {
                            "stage": "TEXT_MATCH",
                            "inputStage": {
                                "stage": "FETCH",
                                "inputStage": {
                                    "stage": "OR",
                                    "inputStage": {
                                        "stage": "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern": {
                                            "_fts": "text",
                                            "_ftsx": 1,
                                            "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1
                                        },
                                        "indexName": "TextIndex",
                                        "isMultiKey": true,
                                        "isUnique": false,
                                        "isSparse": false,
                                        "isPartial": false,
                                        "indexVersion": 2,
                                        "direction": "backward",
                                        "indexBounds": {

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans": []
    },
    "serverInfo": {
        "host": "4794df1ed9c4",
        "port": 27017,
        "version": "4.2.5",
        "gitVersion": "2261279b51ea13df08ae708ff278f0679c59dc32"
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

How can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that sorting the result requires more memory than what is configured.

The field `imagePath` that you want to project is not covered by the `TextIndex` try adding a new index:

```
db.imageProperties.createIndex(
  {
    "imageProperties.cameraMaker": "text",
    "imageProperties.cameraModel": "text",
    "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1,
    "imagePath": 1
  }
)
```

Then try the following steps:

- Check that the indexes are created successfully by running:

```
db.imageProperties.getIndexes()
```

- Check whether the correct index is being used:

```
 db.imageProperties.find( { $text: { $search: "nikon" } }, {"imagePath" : 1, _id: 0 } )
  .sort( { "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1 } ).explain()
```

- If you only want a limited rows of results, also add the limit

```
 db.imageProperties.find( { $text: { $search: "nikon" } }, {"imagePath" : 1, _id: 0 } )
  .sort( { "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1 } ).limit(100)
```

- You can also allow disk usage by using aggregation framework with [`allowDiskUse`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#method-aggregate-allowdiskuse)

```
db.imageProperties.aggregate([{
  $match: { $text: { $search: "nikon" } }
}, {
  $sort: { "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1 }
} , {
  $project: { imagePath: 1 }
}], {
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get: db.imageProperties.find( { $text: { $search: "nikon" } }, {"imagePath" : 1, _id: 0 } ).sort( { "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal": -1 } )
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
        "code" : 96,
        "codeName" : "OperationFailed"

Comment: So you need to query without using limits?

Have you tried using `aggregation` with disk usage enabled? It should not throw error but the query might take a while to execute, I have added the aggregation query in the answer.

Comment: Yes, with limits the memory will not be hit. I would like to understand how to use the index to sort the result-set. According to the documentation that should work, but I can't get it to work. That is the issue.

Comment: @OlavT Can you add the output of `.explain()` to the question? It's possible that you have such a large collection that the index can not fit into RAM.

Comment: I have now added the output from .explain()

Comment: The output of `.explain()` shows that it is using the index. Try to run `db.imageProperties.stats()` to see the size of the collection and the index, it's possible that they are are too large and you actually need to increase the limit.

Comment: Size of the collection is 3240783245. "indexSizes": {
  "_id_": 581632,
  "imagePath_1": 724992,
  "imageProperties.dateTimeOriginal_-1": 987136,
  "TextIndex": 10289152